# passphrase no prompt

Tags: linux, ssh

I have ssh key with passphrase.
I want to keep the passphrase and work without the need to enter every time the passphrase.
Is there any utility with the ssh command (like sshpass) for the passphrase? thanks.

Comment: There is a solution here http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh

Comment: Are you using a desktop environment?  If so, which one?